# JS - jQuery draggable resizable multiple divs in container pushing each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have row with multiple columns inside it. Column width is devided by number of columns, to reach 100% of row width. User is able to update column width by dragging the edge of it. Ive been googling whole day for a script such as this one http://dobtco.github.io/jquery-resizable-columns/ but that would work on divs, not table columns, and no luck.

So i went with draggable solution, but as it does not have "containment" update during drag or after drag. I had to change draggable.js file, and it works - http://itsgoran.com/draggable/ , but i would prefer not to change draggable.js file.

I added:

```
o.containment = [parseInt(this.offsetParent.offset().left) + 40,0,parseInt(this.offsetParent.next().offset().left + this.offsetParent.next().width() - 40),0];
```

inside "_setContainment" method.

And inside `_mouseStop()` event, called `this._setContainment();`

Is there a way around this, so that i dont have to change core file ? Or some other script that would work?

Just calling _setContainment() method didnt work either.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it by adding whole code to the function and running it again during "stop" callback. That way draggable is reinitiated again with updated containment. BUT i am not sure about memory usage this way ?

Here is the full code:

```
function init_draggable(){
            $(".ui-draggable").each(function(){
                var $this = $(this);
                var $left = parseInt($(this).parent().offset().left) + 100,
                $right = parseInt($(this).parent().next().offset().left) +  50;
                console.log($left);
                $(this).draggable({ 
                  axis: 'x', 
                  refreshPositions: true,
                  start: function(event, ui) {
                    elWidth = $(this).parent().width();
                    nextWidth = $(this).parent().next().width();
                  },
                  drag: function(event, ui) {
                    $(this).parent().width( elWidth + (ui.position.left-ui.originalPosition.left) );
                    $(this).parent().next().width( nextWidth - (ui.position.left-ui.originalPosition.left) );
                  },
                  stop: function(event, ui) {
                    $(".ui-draggable").each(function(){
                        $(this).css({"left":'auto','right':'0'});
                    });
                    init_draggable();
                  },
                    containment: [parseInt($(this).parent().offset().left) + 40,0,parseInt($(this).parent().next().offset().left + $(this).parent().next().width() - 40),0]
                });
            });
        }

        init_draggable();
```